# How to store and retrieve the position of an html div element from Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div which is a box and i made it draggable using a method i found here in SO,and i want to have persistence of its position across same-origin windows and on page reloads.
My logic is to use 2 buttons,the first one sets the box's position to a fixed place and stores its left,top values to Local Storage.
The second one deletes the first one's entry from L.S. and sets a new one after the box was being dragged to somewhere else.
Then i use a function which loads on page start,to retrieve whatever values is saved in L.S. at any given time and sets the box position to the last saved position.
It works for saving and retrieving the fixed position but not for the moved position.
Is this a valid logic and the right approach and how can i do it ?
Please have into consideration that i am a noob!

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id="fixedpositionsbutton" style="width: 80px; height: 50px; font-size: 17" onclick="fixedposition()">Fixed Position</button>
<button id="pinnedpositionsbutton" style="width: 80px; height: 50px; font-size: 17" onclick="setPinnedPositionItemToLocalStorage()">Pinned Position</button>
<div id="draggable-div">DRAG THIS
</div>
<div id="fixedposition">FIXED POSITION</div>
<style>
    #draggable-div{
  cursor: move;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
 line-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, lightblue);    
  border-color: black;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 15%;
  position: absolute;
    }
  #fixedposition{
        font-size: 24;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 200px;
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
        left: 74px;
        top: 74px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        height: 215px;
        width: 215px;
    }
</style>
<script>

    //Makes the DIV element draggagle:

dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable-div"));
var draggable = document.getElementById("draggable-div");


function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }


  
function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
  
}

//SETS THE DRAGGABLE DIV TO FIXED POSITION AND ALSO STORES ITS POSITION TO LOCAL STORAGE
    
  function fixedposition(){
    
    draggable.style.left = "80px";
    draggable.style.top = "80px";
    localStorage.setItem("draggable-left", draggable.style.left);
    localStorage.setItem("draggable-top", draggable.style.top);
    
}  

    //DELETES THE PREVIOUS FIXED POSITION ENTRY FROM LOCAL STORAGE AND STORES THE NEW ONE AFTER IT WAS DRAGGED SOMEWHERE ELSE
    
function setPinnedPositionItemToLocalStorage(){
    
    
    localStorage.removeItem("draggable-left");
    localStorage.removeItem("draggable-top");
    localStorage.setItem("draggable-left", draggable.style.left);
    localStorage.setItem("draggable-top", draggable.style.top);
    
}
    

  // RETRIEVES THE DIV'S POSITION FROM LOCAL STORAGE  
    
    (function RetrieveValueFromLocalStorage() {
    
    draggable.style.top = localStorage.getItem("draggable-top");
    draggable.style.left = localStorage.getItem("draggable-left");

//immediate function is called on page loading and sets input value from localstorage
})();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/vaggelis-magonezos/pen/LYZmEVm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep your console open you will see the error.

Your function is named `setPinnedPositionItemToLocalStorage()` (camelCase) but you are setting the click handler for it by saying `onclick="SetPinnedPositionItemToLocalStorage()"` (PascalCase). They must be consistent, as Javascript is case-sensitive.